# "NameError: name 'click' is not defined" error when assigning a method to a tkinter button, and button is not appearing on window?

Tags: python, class, tkinter, button, methods

I am a bit of a beginner so bear with me. Ive been working with tkinter and ive been trying to call **click()** method to act when *button1* is clicked. However, *button1* is never created in the window when i run the program, and it keeps returning the "NameError: name 'click' is not defined", when i set **click()** as *button1*'s command.

Ive tried to put the **click()** method before the creation of *self.button* or even before the **init**, but it still returns the same error.
Is there any better way to call a **click()** when *button1* is pressed?

EDIT:

Heres a bit more information:

so i put the creation of the window, **Tk()**, and the labels within the same class, and so with that im putting in all the parameters for the initial config of the window by "app = App(thing, 'hello world')" and then creating some labels just for testing.

by setting up the methods in the label classes, ive made it so i only have to input a few things when creating them, but i might have to forego that with *args **kwargs.

The **Format()** method is so that i dont have to repeat as much **.grid()** methods.

the **click()** is the method that is supposed to be executed when *button1* is pressed, which is supposed to open up a window for the user to select a directory and then printed out.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import filedialog



thing = Tk()

class App():
    def __init__(self, master, _title, back='white'):
        self.master = master
        self._title = _title
        self.back = back
        self.master.title(self._title)
        self.master.configure(background=back)
        self.l_label = None
        self.w = None
        self._text = None
        self.l_label = None
        self.Row = None
        self.Column = None
        self.Command = None
    

   def label(self, _text, back, w=50, h=50):
        self.back = back
        self.w = w
        self.h = h
        self._text = _text
        self.l_label = Label(self.master, text=self._text, bg=self.back, width=self.w, height=self.h)
        return self

    def Format(self, Row=1, Column=1):
        self.Row = Row
        self.Column = Column
        self.l_label.grid(row=Row, column=Column)
        return self

class button():

    def __init__(self, master, _text, back, Command, w=50, h=50):
        super().__init__(_text, back, w=50, h=50)
        self.Command = Command
        self.Row = None
        self.Column = None
        save_dir = None
        self.b_button = Button(self.master, text = _text, bg = back, width = w, height =  h, command = Command )
        return b_button

    def click(self):
        save_dir = self.b_button.filedilog.askdirectory()
        print(save_dir)

    def Format(self, Row=1, Column=1):
        self.Row = Row
        self.Column = Column
        self.b_button.grid(row=Row, column=Column)
        return self


app = App(thing, 'hello world')
label = app.label('this is something to look at lol', 'white',100,1 ).Format(3,3)
label2 = app.label('this is a label', 'brown', 10,10).Format(4,3)
button1 = button('this is a button', 'white', click, 50,50 ).Format(5,3)
thing.mainloop()
```

Comment: Well there are several ways to achieve this and unfortunately you did a bit of a mess here and it seems not clear to me what you try to achieve with this code. Can you give us some more information about what this code is supposed to do and why you did it like you did?

Comment: alright, ill get back to that, ill include the whole code, it is a bit of a mess hah